# how to change ViewResolvers from jsp to HTML View?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new    InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
}
```

I changed viewResolver.setSuffix(".html"); now I am getting 404 error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);`. Try to remove it and test again.

Comment: Hi hamed, thanks for your replay. I followed u r in instruction.but again i got same 404 error.  DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /index.html DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/index.html] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/BullTrends/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'